# Why nvim (vim) adds \< and \> to search pattern and what they means?

Tags: vim, neovim

I use the `*` command to fill the search register (`/`) with the current word (under cursor) so I don't have to paste it into the substitute command.
To do a find and replace I can do it quickly like so:

```
:%s//MyNewValue/g
```

instead of

```
:%s/MyOldValue/MyNewValue/g
```

But sometimes I just want to change one character in the word (like a typo). So after I used `*` on the word, I do the following:

```
:%s//<c-r>//g
```

But I get this:

```
:%s//\<MyOldValue\>/g
```

because the `/` register contains `\<MyOldValue\>`.

So, here's my question:

How can I get rid of these `\<` and `\>`? Or is there a better way to edit all occurrences of a word in vim?

The only way I found, it's to yank the word and paste it twice in the substitute pattern.

```
yiw
:%s/<c-r>"/<c-r>"/g
```

Also, what do `\<` and `\>` mean and what are they use for?

Comment: BTW, please don't write "I'm a total noob with [...]". We all are or were at some point. Respect yourself. If anything, it will decrease your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\<` and `\>` are *word boundaries*, see `:help \<` or `:help \>`.

This is similar to the "match whole word" checkbox in the search dialog of graphical editors.

For example, it will do the following:

```
Put the cursor on "foo" and press star.
It will match foo in this line.
But not foobar in this one.
```

If you don't want this, use `g*` instead of `*`. It will not add the word boundaries.

If you're using the `:substitute` command, you may as well use <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> for words-with-non-word-characters) to add the word under your cursor to the command line. In Vim, one would write it like this:

```
:%s/<C-R><C-W>/MyNewValue/
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` does add `\< \>` because that is the regex to just search for whole words. See `:h star` for that. I guess the solution to your problem is to not use `*` in the second step, but to use `<c-r> + <c-w>`. This does copy the word under the cursor into the commandline. Since `*` jumps to a search result, this is always the word you want.